# i am making a responsive form in angular using the bootstrap and css but i am not able to set the width of the submit button in it

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a responsive form in angular using bootstrap and css but 
when it runs on mobile the hamburger is overlapping  the other content 
(signup and signin).

The code below is for navigation bar -:
    **`app.component.html`:~**

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#nav">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">pink scissor</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/signup">sign up</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/signin">sign in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The code below is for the signup form
    **`signup.component.html`:~**

```
<div class="container-fluid hail">
  <span>
    <h5>welcome to </h5>
    <h1>pink seccior</h1>
    <p>
      log in to get the moment updates of the things
      <br>
      that interest you
    </p>
  </span>

  <form action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>

    <span>already have a account ?
      <a routerLink="/signin">sign in</a>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

*I thought when I would click the hamburger icon it would shift the form down but it is overlapping the form.*